# Can't configure host url on WebApplicationFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, testing, integration

I am trying to host my api project using WebApplicationFactory. I have overriden ConfigureWebHost and added my desired url in UseUrls() method. I am setting the app to host on http://localhost:5000, but it is inaccessible from browser. The only way to call endpoints in the host is via httpClient created by CreateClient() method in WebApplicationFactory instance.

```
public class ApiHubFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
    {
        public string HostUrl { get; set; } = "https://localhost:5001";
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", HostUrl);

            //Adding fake authentication scheme to bypass JWT authentication
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = TestAuthHandler.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultScheme = TestAuthHandler.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = TestAuthHandler.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(TestAuthHandler.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });
            });
        }
}
```

I have tried to find out on what url the host is starting looking in httpclient. Despite I have set it to be http://localhost:5000, it is 127.0.0.1:80, which is also inaccessible from browser.

Also I have tried using settings, the answer is from [How to configure url on Host created by WebApplicationFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67047849/how-to-configure-url-on-host-created-by-webapplicationfactory)

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Notice there is no `--` prefix in "urls"
        builder.UseSetting("urls", "http://localhost:1234");

        // other stuff as usual
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with https?

Comment: yes, it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `WebApplicationFactory` crates a whole application in memory, that is accessible only with `HttpCLient` that is created with the factory.

```
WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory=...;
var client = _factory.CreateClient();
```

There is no other way to access your API. If this is what you really need then you can create just a regular **WebHost** like you are doing in your Program file and run an API in **Kestrel**.

```
public sealed class ApiTestHost: IDisposable
{
    public const string HostUrl = "http://localhost:54318";
    private readonly IWebHost host;

    public ApiTestHost()
    {
        host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls(HostUrl )
            .Build();
        host.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        host?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then you can just create an instance of `ApiTestHost` in every test but better to use smth like `IClassFixture`

If you want to stay with WebApplicationFactory you can refer to this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)